# how to have checking on date on csv upload PHP

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

```
$ayear=date("Y") + 1 ; 
$lyear=date("Y") - 1 ;
$cyear=date("Y") ;
```

some code here

```
        fgetcsv($handle);
        while($data=fgetcsv($handle)){

            $item0=($data[0]);
            $item1=($data[1]);
            if(!empty($data[2])){
                if((date('Y', strtotime(($data[2]))) >= $lyear) && (date('Y', strtotime(($data[2]))) <= $ayear) ){
                    $item2=date('Ymd', strtotime(($data[2])));
                }else{
                    header("Location: index.php?success=date");
                }

            }else{
                // $item2=($data[2]);
                header("Location: index.php?success=date");
                break;
            }
            $item3=($data[3]);
```

how can i check the years on the column date on upload process
it needs to allow years that is current year and next year and last year

example current year is 2022 it needs to allow 2023 , 2022 and 2021

i aim to prevent upload dates that are way beyond, like "5029" or "1990"

Comment: Put the allowed years into an array, and then use `in_array` ...?

Comment: Thank you for this  it works now

```   if(in_array(date('Y', strtotime(($data[2]))), $arryear)){
     $item2=date('Ymd', strtotime(($data[2])));
    }else{
     header("Location: index.php?success=date");
     break;
    }```

Comment: Add a proper Answer below if you got a solution. No-one can find it or vote on it if you hide it in the comments

Comment: i have another question how can i display what row that has an error ?

Comment: Why was this question tagged with mysql? I see no parts of the code that interacts with mysql, nor does the question indicates issues with mysql.

Comment: If you have a new problem, ask a new question about it. Don't ask in the comments or in an answer, as it will not be seen there, and no-one can post answers in response either. Remember that stackoverflow has a clear question-and-answer format for each post, it doesn't work like a discussion forum or anything like that. Take the [tour] if you're not sure how to use the site fully.

Comment: thanks @ADyson  , just a bit new to the site :)

Comment: I figured...that's why I made the suggestion :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ayear=date("Y") + 1 ;
$lyear=date("Y") - 1 ;
$cyear=date("Y") ;
$arryear = array($ayear,$cyear,$lyear);
```

some code here

```
if(in_array(date('Y', strtotime(($data[2]))), $arryear)){
    $item2=date('Ymd', strtotime(($data[2])));
}else{
    header("Location: index.php?success=date");
    break;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).